# Any way to use a vector of raw bytes as an archive for boost serialization?

Tags: c++, vector, boost-serialization

I have written some code that receives messages over a serial link and, at the moment, the message data ends up in a std::vector. What I'd like to do with it is use boost::serialization (probably) mechanisms to pull the message apart into class members. I've been searching around for how to do this, and I've found a number of what seem to be the pieces of the jigsaw, but I'm a bit stuck putting it all together.

There are various examples that get me so far, and some run, but don't work, so I'd appreciate some help (partly because I've got through so much stuff my brain is feeling a bit fried).

The gist of it is that I have a class in DataIn.hpp, e.g.:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>

class DataIn
{
public:
    DataIn() : m_a(4), m_b(5), m_c(6), m_d(7) {};
    virtual ~DataIn() {};

    void PrintDetails()
    {
        std::cout << "m_a " << static_cast<unsigned int>(m_a) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "m_b " << static_cast<unsigned int>(m_b) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "m_c " << static_cast<unsigned int>(m_c) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "m_d " << static_cast<unsigned int>(m_d) << std::endl;
    }

private:
    uint8_t m_a;
    uint8_t m_b;
    uint8_t m_c;
    uint8_t m_d;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & m_a;
        ar & m_b;
        ar & m_c;
        ar & m_d;
    }
};
```

In my test driver program I have:

```
#include "DataIn.hpp"

#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void doArchiveStuff()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> data{ 8, 9, 10, 11 };
    boost::iostreams::array_source source{reinterpret_cast<char *>(data.data()), data.size()};
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::array_source> is{source};
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia{is, boost::archive::archive_flags::no_header};

    DataIn dataIn;
    dataIn.PrintDetails();
    ia >> dataIn;
    dataIn.PrintDetails();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting..." << std::endl;
    doArchiveStuff();

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles and links but, when I run it, I get:

```
Starting...
m_a 4
m_b 5
m_c 6
m_d 7
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  input stream error
```

I may be just misunderstanding how this is meant to work but it's always possibly I'm just missing a step, so I thought I'd ask here.

If anyone can make a suggestion that would help I'd appreciate it enormously.

Comment: Which line triggers the exception?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Seems to be "ia >> dataIn;". If I step through with the debugger (gdb) it doesn't get as far as the serialize() in the DataIn class. The exception's being raised in basic_binary_iprimitive.hpp, line 164, where it's just checked "if(scount != s)" (from boost 1.53 - sorry, there's a good reason why I'm using something that old, although I suspect it may not be a contributory factor?). In this case scount = 3 and s = 4.

Comment: I realise you must use 1.53, but temporarily try the same MCVE with new Boost and see whether it works. This sounds like a bug in your version of Boost. (There are some similar-ish examples in the bug history)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for that suggestion. I've tried it in the latest version and the behaviour's identical.

Answer (score 0):

A Boost archive isn't just a byte representation of a struct. It's a complex thing with metadata (e.g. type information) even though you've turned off the header.

If you serialise your struct and examine the results, you should see that it's (a) not what your array contains, and (b) more than four bytes.

So your input is just not a valid Boost binary archive. In this case it seems to be, among other things, too small, triggering a stream underflow.

You should only try to deserialise things that you serialised using the same mechanism.

Comment: Bit of a guess but easily verifiable. Let us know!

Comment: To be honest, that was the conclusion I'd come to, as I'd looked at what went into a text_ostream when I serialsed a vector to it. I'd hoped switching the header off (actually I tried switching off all the flags) would've done something more useful (for want of a better word). I was also hoping for a 'to do what you want, you need to do blah blah', which could've helped me not feel I've totally wasted a load of time on this!

Comment: @cosimo193 Ultimately, if all Boost.Serialise did was cast to `char*` and write to a file, it would be pretty pointless because you can trivially do that yourself :P As for telling you how to do what you want, you'd need to actually tell us what you want.

Comment: 'Trivially' isn't really the word, if you want to implement an elegant, object-oriented and/or template-based mechanism with the elegance of boost::serialization, as far as I can see.